# Change Tracking has cleaned up tracking information although Auto Clean up is set to false

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, change-tracking

On my SQL Server I have change tracking enabled, auto cleanup set to false or to true with a very high retention period like 364 days.

Using Microsoft Sync Framework I sync the first time successfully, the second time I try to sync I get the error

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): SQL Server Change
>   Tracking has cleaned up tracking information for table 'TableName'. To
>   recover from this error, the client must reinitialize its local
>   database and try again".

Why is the tracking information being cleaned although the auto clean up is set to false?

I tried the solution posted by this [article](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/uklaunch2007ado.net/thread/0e2dd016-5d14-4cf9-aebc-93b762b42ec7), but it did not work for me, when I run the reinitialize code it takes forever and the RAM usage keeps building until I get out of memory exception.

Please note that my database is big, over 400 MB, the total number of records synced is over 163,000 record, the first sync takes a long time so resorting to deleting the local CE database when this error happens is not an option.

Comment: have you done anything on the server database? ie., truncate table? etc...

Comment: Nothing changed on the server, not even Data.

Comment: are you copying over SQL Ce databases from different locations? the error can also appear if the sync anchors on the SQL Ce database got reset.

Comment: No I do not copy it from anywhere, the SQL CE database is created using the sync logic.

Comment: ten months after, what have you done to fix it? I tried same solution (article) to recover client data, but it didn't work... In my case, I forgot to set retention days to more than 2 days...

Comment: Have a similar issue, although can't reliably reproduce when it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem occurs when I restore the server database from backup and before any change has happened on the database.

So the simple solution was that after I restore the database from backup I just go and update any column of any row in any tracked table and that fixes the problem!